# How to get a list of the event handlers bound to an event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

Given an element, let's say a `div`, is it possible to obtain a list of the handlers bound to a specific event fired by the element?

```
/* pseudo code: click on a div handlers? */
document.getElementById('myDiv').getHandlers('click');
```

**Edit**

Ok, here's some more details. I want to bind  a click handler to a div, unless another handler is already bound to the div. What I have in mind is the following:

```
/* pseudo code: click on a div handlers? */
if(!document.getElementById('myDiv').getHandlers('click'))
   document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click', myEventhandler);
```

Comment: This is why when I bind handlers I give them unique names. You can even store the name in a data attribute on the element.

Comment: It's not possible if you are using pure DOM, but possible if you use framework like jQuery. This has already been answered in more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node (see second answer)

Comment: @Bergi: I have already read suggested duplicates. But in no case I found a programmatically way to obtain a list of the handlers. Suggested answer regards debugging or using jQuery.

Comment: @ADC: Yes, because there is none.

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not possible with DOM methods.

However, some libraries store all handlers they bind in element-associated data structures to enable methods like `unbindAll`.